# Freeradius Version 2.2.8 sql issue

Tags: mysql, freeradius

```
Error: [sql] Couldn't insert SQL accounting START record - Can't update table 'useraccounting' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
```

We get the above error frequently after the user authenticated and it take more than 1 min for the user to appear in online table. Any idea about the cause and solutions?

Thanks

Update:
Below the trigger that is used:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`mysql`@`%` TRIGGER `radacct_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `radacct` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  if (NEW.acctoutputoctets != OLD.acctoutputoctets)
  THEN
    UPDATE useraccounting SET tmpQuta = tmpQuta + (New.acctoutputoctets - OLD.acctoutputoctets)
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.userable_id = useraccounting.client_id AND users.userable_type = 'App\\Models\\Client' AND (users.username = New.username));
  END IF;
END
```

UPDATE2: we have created 2 triggers. One on INSERT and another one on UPDATE.

After INSERT on radacct:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE useraccounting SET tmpQuta = New.acctoutputoctets
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.userable_id = useraccounting.client_id AND users.userable_type = 'App\\Models\\Client' AND (users.username = New.username));
END
```

after UPDATE on radacct:

```
BEGIN
  if (NEW.acctoutputoctets != OLD.acctoutputoctets)
  THEN
    UPDATE useraccounting SET tmpQuta = tmpQuta + (New.acctoutputoctets - OLD.acctoutputoctets)
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.userable_id = useraccounting.client_id AND users.userable_type = 'App\\Models\\Client' AND (users.username = New.username));
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: I think reading the error is quite explanatory. Show what triggers are on the useraccounting table and what is the stored procedures called.  What triggers - `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS WHERE EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE='useraccounting'`. `SHOW CREATE TRIGGER {triggername}` / `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE {procedurename}`. `SHOW CREATE TABLE useraccounting` might  be useful too.

Comment: Thanks @danblack for your reply. I updated post with the trigger

Comment: Good start. The second part of the error is `already used by statement which invoked this stored ..trigger`.  So you need to know what SQL statement that updates both `radacct` and `useraccounting` tables; or updates `radacct` and uses `useraccounting` in the same query.

Comment: Aside I think a neater from of the trigger without an `if` statement would be `UPDATE useraccounting,users SET tmpQuta = tmpQuta + (New.acctoutputoctets - OLD.acctoutputoctets) AND NEW.acctoutputoctets != OLD.acctoutputoctets WHERE users.userable_id = useraccounting.client_id AND users.userable_type = 'App\\Models\\Client' AND (users.username = New.username) AND NEW.acctoutputoctets != OLD.acctoutputoctet`

Comment: Thanks again @danblack. we have created 2 triggers. One on INSERT and another one on UPDATE as you can see in UPDATE2

Comment: Show the SQL generating the error.